# ROS Message API Documentation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having trouble getting ROS message links to work correctly.  I have a page: [Industrial Robot Spec](http://ros.org/wiki/Industrial/Industrial_Robot_Driver_Spec), that has auto-generated links to ROS messages.  For example:`<<MsgLink(sensor_msgs/JointState)>>` generates this link: http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/JointState.html.  The generated link is valid

A similar example:`<<MsgLink(industrial_msgs/RobotStatus)>>` generates this link:
http://www.ros.org/doc/api/industrial_msgs/html/msg/RobotStatus.html.  The generated link is invalid.

The message documentation for the RobotStatus message does exist here:
http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/industrial_msgs/html/msg/RobotStatus.html

How do I get the MsgLink macro to point to ros.org/doc/groovy/api or how do I get the message api docs to populate: [www.ros.org/doc/api/](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49515/ros-message-api-documentation/) by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1601 on 2012-11-30

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have not yet any idea for your 2nd question. For the 1st question,

> How do I get the MsgLink macro to point to ros.org/doc/groovy/api

Looking at the code of macro [MsgLink](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/roswiki/blob/ae0cd80627e0e3952e5f6b6c306d053c8bc3b016/macro/MsgLink.py), there might not be a way to do that. I [opened up a ticket](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/roswiki/issues/15) (I have a feeling this ticket might not be prioritized. That said patch is very welcomed).

ps. Your workaround (to use fullpath URL) might be enough (not ideal for sure) for many situations though

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreasGustavsson](https://answers.ros.org/users/39033/andreasgustavsson/) on 2018-12-15**:
As far as I can tell, this is still an issue and I use hard-coded URLs.

I had a look at the code for MsgLink and it seems that one solution could be to add a second case beside MsgLink(msg/type); something like MsgLink(distro/msg/type). But I do not know how appropriate this would be, though.